# Tricky functional equation: $f\!\left(\frac{2-p+p^2}{4-2p}\right) - f(p/2)= f\!\left(\frac{(1-p)(2+p)}{2-p}\right) - f(1-p)$

Tags: functional-equations

I have (expect there exists) a function $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ for which the following relationship holds:
$$
f\left(\frac{2-p+p^2}{4-2p}\right) - f(p/2)
=f\left(\frac{(1-p)(2+p)}{2-p}\right) - f(1-p),
$$
for all $p\in(0,1)$.
(Possibly there is a nice choice of $p$ that makes this look nicer.)

I know the function is smooth, monotonously increasing, and goes to infinity as its argument goes to 1 (respectively to $-\infty$ when the argument goes to 0.) That is, it's the inverse of a sigmoid function.

I think the above characterization should be enough to determine the function, at least up to some scaling and translation (if $f(x) = a g(x) + b$ clearly $a$ and $b$ cancel.)

Besides that I have no idea about how I might go about finding $f$. I don't even know how I could try to compute it numerically. Any help greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: Maybe it's nicer to state like this:
$$
\begin{align}
&f\left(p_1\frac{1-p_2p_3}{(1-p_2)(1-p_3)}\right)-f(p_1)
\\ =&f\left(p_2\frac{1-p_1p_3}{(1-p_1)(1-p_3)}\right)-f(p_2)
\\ =&f\left(p_3\frac{1-p_1p_2}{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}\right)-f(p_3)
\end{align}
$$
for any choice of $p_1,p_2,p_3\ge 0, p_1+p_2+p_3=1$.

The formulation above comes from considering $p_1=p_2=p/2$ and $p_3=1-p$.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to ask:

> Does there exists a monotonically increasing function, $f:(0,1)\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ so that $$f\!\left(\frac{2-p+p^2}{2(2-p)}\right) - f(p/2)=
f\!\left(\frac{ 2+p-p^2}{2-p}\right) - f(1-p),$$  $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} = \infty$ and  $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} = -\infty$

Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you, yes. That's a better formulation.
Let's cut the part about the limits, since I don't really care what happens there--it's only my intuition about how the function should behave.

Comment: @ThomasAhle If you don't care about the limits, doesn't $f \equiv 0$ work? Do you mean "strictly increasing"?

Comment: Ok, you are right. I need to either care about the limits or require it to be strictly monotonic. I think the later is the better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least your “nicer” version has no solution.  At $p_1 = 0.6, p_2 = 0.03, p_3 = 0.37$, we have

$$f(0.970938) - f(0.6) = f(0.092619) - f(0.03).$$

At $p_1 = 0.03, p_2 = 0.092619, p_3 = 0.877381$, we have

$$f(0.247722) - f(0.03) = f(0.758204) - f(0.092619).$$

At $p_1 = 0.247722, p_2 = 0.662382, p_3 = 0.089896$, we have

$$f(0.758204) - f(0.247722) = f(0.945929) - f(0.662382).$$

Adding these three equations and canceling yields

$$f(0.970938) - f(0.6) = f(0.945929) - f(0.662382).$$

But for $f$ to be strictly increasing, the left side must be greater than the right side.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!